# Athena query performance between similar queries differs significantly

Tags: amazon-athena

Noticed the other day that there are some significant differences in query performance when running two nearly identical queries.

QUERY 1:

```
SELECT * FROM "table" 
WHERE (badge = 'xyz' or badge = 'abc') 
    and ((year = '2021' and month = '11' and day = '1') 
            or (year = '2021' and month = '10' and day = '31')) 
ORDER BY timestamp
```

Runtime: 40.751 sec

Data scanned: 94.06 KB

QUERY 2:

```
SELECT * FROM "table" 
WHERE (badge = 'xyz' or badge = 'abc') 
    and ((year = '2021' and month = '10' and day = '30') 
            or (year = '2021' and month = '10' and day = '31')) 
ORDER BY timestamp
```

Runtime: 1.78 sec

Data scanned: 216.86 KB

The only major difference between the two is that one query looks at 11/1 & 10/31 and the other looks at 10/31 & 10/30. So there is an additional month partition being looked at in QUERY 1.

When running both queries
with EXPLAIN I
noticed that
QUERY 2 uses a TableScan while QUERY1 uses a ScanFilter.

Anyone know why this might be the case between these two queries?

Additional Details:

Time in queue for both queries was sub 1 second.

In s3, the data is structured as follows:

badge=%s/year=%s/month=%s/day=%s/hour=%s

badge,year,month,day & hour are all partitions defined via Partition Projection.

Comment: Second query also has `limit 10`.

Comment: Copy pasted wrong, sorry about that. I was trying to get it to not use a ScanFilter but it made no difference (The question still stands).